# ora-00020 maximum number of processes

Tags: oracle

Recently, I have been facing this error

```
 ora-00020 maximum number of processes
```

I have read articles that says that I have to increase the number of processes, sessions, and the transactions. 
I tried. and Simply I have done the followings: 
I logged in as SYSDBA to the database. 
I tried to use the following command:

```
alter system set processes = 500 scope = psfile
```

to increase the sessions and the transactions I need to follow the equations below : 
sessions = (1.1*processes) + 5 
transactions = (1.1*sessions)
well, I am not sure if it's correct or not. 
so, I tried to increase the processes first by the command above. 
I got another error

```
 [code] ora-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified[/code]
```

After reading about ora-02095. I found that I have to check the scope if it's spfile or pfile.

```
SELECT DECODE(value, NULL, 'PFILE', 'SPFILE') "Init File Type"
FROM sys.v_$parameter WHERE name = 'spfile';
no rows selected
```

can you please help me

Comment: `scope = psfile` is a typo. But did you make the typo *here* or when you ran it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution : 
Go to database files
go to ADMIN\database\pfile\init.ora
open it
change
processes = 59
to 
processes = 200
then shutdown and start the database. 
Problem Solved. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd as Administrator
2. C:\Users\Usuario> sqlplus "/as sysdba"
3. SQL> alter system set processes=500 scope=spfile;
4. SQL> shutdownimmediate
5. SQL> startup
6. SQL> show parameter processes